# How can I save images from a map with cv2.imwrite

Tags: python, dictionary, neural-network, save, opencv

I want to save with cv2.imwrite images that are contained in a map called "map_result".
I tried by converting the map into a list and then save the list with imwrite.
`map_result = preprocessor.get_map(masks)`
 `list_result = list(map_result)`
`cv2.imwrite('map.jpg', list_result)`
But it returns:
**TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'list_result'**
How can I save the images correctly in order to display them?